# c# websocket - send file to chrome problem - websocket text frames over 131k get truncated

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, websocket, file-transfer

when send file to c# server with chrome and js, first received chunk that includes data length, for every file is 131000. however in firefox data length equal to file size
what's a problem?

based on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=517090 the subject of this bug is "websocket text frames over 131k get truncated"

c#

```
if (dataLength == 126)
{
    indexFirstMask = 4;
    dataLength = bytes[3] | bytes[2] << 8;
}
else if (dataLength == 127)
{
    indexFirstMask = 10;
    dataLength = bytes[9] | bytes[8] << 8 | bytes[7] << 16 | bytes[6] << 24 | bytes[5] << 32 |
        bytes[4] << 40 | bytes[3] << 48 | bytes[2] << 56;
}
```

js:

```
connect:function(){
    var root = this;
    root.websocket = new WebSocket(root.url);
    root.websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
    root.websocket.onopen = () => root.fireEvent('connect');
    root.websocket.onmessage = (e) => {
        root.fireEvent('receive',JSON.parse(e.data));
    }
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
        root.websocket.onclose = function () {}; 
        root.websocket.close();
    });
},

sendMessage:function(msg){
    var root = this;
    root.controller.websocket.send(msg);
},
sendFile:function(){
    var root = this;
    var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
    var root = this;
    var loader = new FileReader();
    loader.onload = (e) => {
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        root.buffer = byteArray.buffer;
        root.byteLength = root.buffer.byteLength;
        root.server.websocket.send(root.buffer);
    }
    loader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: So the first thing I see is that in sendMessage, you have a 'msg' parameter but are sending 'message'

Comment: Also if you look at the documentation on the linkyou posted, it says that Chrome may break up large messages to save memory / for performance reasons

Comment: @ControlAltDel Fixed, thank you
Yes, it divides the file and send it
My problem is that no matter how I decode the frame, it doesn't work in Chrome, however it works in Firefox.